# MAMP: php.ini - mbstring.http_input - Disabling for Drupal

Tags: php, drupal, mamp

Updated my MAMP to the most current [3.0.7.2] since I have OSX 10.10 now. Having issues with installing any new Drupal installations locally now. Error - mbstring.http_input must be disabled.

I have checked the php.ini being loaded in from `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/conf/php.ini`and shows it is disabled.

I read into this and tried setting it to auto/off/false/pass, no luck. - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-http-input.php

Am I missing something? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling mbstring.http_input using `php.ini` file should work. But maybe you changed the `php.ini` file for an unloaded php version (because MAMP comes with many php versions, php5.6.2 in your case).

You can try disabling mbstring.http_input from `.htaccess` file. Just copy these lines to the file.

```
php_value mbstring.http_input pass
php_value mbstring.http_output pass
```

Or via `settings.php` file:

```
ini_set('mbstring.http_input', 'pass');
ini_set('mbstring.http_output', 'pass');
```

Comment: What I thought also. Is there a way to find out when one is being loaded? Right now the 5.6.2 should be the one used since that's what I have MAMP set to. Like some method of how you'd check on a server with php --ini. I could change every single one if it comes down to it, I just don't understand why it's doing this.

Comment: use phpinfo() inside an empty php file, open it on a browser. You should find the path to loaded php.ini next to (Loaded configuration file) field.

Comment: I used the one that MAMP comes with (what I used to make sure I had the correct php.ini file). I went ahead and made a new php info file and placed it in the root of my Drupal. Says 5.6.2 here too. I went ahead and just placed the 2 ini_set's into my settings.php you had above and I can now install the site. I'll look more into this MAMP issue I'm having later this week. Thanks for the info.