# mbstring and php 5.6.22

Tags: php, mbstring

Script: Drupal  8.1.3, php 5.6.22

php.ini settings:

[image: php.ini settings]

.htaccess:

[image: htacess]

About once a minute, I get following errors in error_log file:

```
[23-Jun-2016 13:48:49 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jun-2016 13:48:51 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Unknown: Use of mbstring.http_input is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
[23-Jun-2016 13:48:51 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Unknown: Use of mbstring.http_output is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: Why are you setting `php_value mbstring.http_input pass` (and `mbstring.http_output`)?  What happens if you get rid of those lines in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: What does your PHP code look like, or is it just a standard Drupal install?  Can you search the code (using `grep` maybe) for `HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36339175/206403

Comment: I didn't change anything. I use default files of Drupal 8 (htaccess,...)

Comment: Can I remove those lines?

Comment: Probably.  Try it and see what happens.  You can always put them back if it doesn't help.

Comment: Can I set permissions of error_log to 400?

Comment: You mean set the `error_log` read-only?  I wouldn't.  You can edit the php.ini to tell it to stop logging to a file, if you really want (see: http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).  It's better to fix the errors than to jut hide them.

Comment: after removing from htaccess, encountered the following error : [23-Jun-2016 20:19:07 UTC] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '........' (111) in /home/***/public_html/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79